# JDBI3: Mapping bean class didn't find any matching columns in result set when mapping to JoinRow

Tags: java, lombok, jdbi, jdbi3, jdbi3-core

I have SQL schema and Java class for issue and ticket model defined as follow:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Ticket {

    private long id;
    private int ticket_int_1;
    private int ticket_int_2;
    private int ticket_int_3;
    private String ticket_varchar_1;
    private String dateFiled;
    private String dateLastUpdated;
    private String dateResolved;
}
```

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@ToString

public class Issue {
    private long id;
    private long issue_bigInt_1;
    private long issue_bigInt_2;
    private int issue_int_1;
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private long issue_bigInt_3;
    private int issue_int_2;
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private int issue_int_3;
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private String issue_varchar_1;
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private String issue_varchar_2;
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    private String issue_varchar_3;
    private int issue_int_4;
    private String dateResolved;
    private String dateCreated;
    private String dateUpdate;
}
```

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class TicketIssue {
    private long id;
    private int ticket_issue_int_1;
    private long issueId; // issue will be the many
    private long ticketId;  // ticket will be the 1
}
```

According to the [official doc](https://jdbi.org/#_beanmapper), I wrote the following code:

```
String selectSql = "SELECT t.*, i.* FROM " + ISSUE_TABLE + " as i"
        + " JOIN " + TICKET_ISSUES_TABLE + " as ti on i.id = ti.issue_id"
        + " JOIN " + TICKET_TABLE + " as t on ti.ticket_id = t.id";

jdbi.useHandle(handle -> 
        handle.registerRowMapper(BeanMapper.factory(Ticket.class, "t"))
        .registerRowMapper(BeanMapper.factory(Issue.class, "i"))
        .registerRowMapper(JoinRowMapper.forTypes(Ticket.class, Issue.class))
        .createQuery(selectSql)
        .mapTo(JoinRow.class));
```

Executing above query throws an error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapping bean class Ticket didn't find any matching columns in result set

My implementation looks exactly the same with the documentation, what went wrong here? Can anyone help?

Comment: Try removing the Lombok `@Builder` annotation. The Jdbi documentation mentions "_The standard bean convention requires that the setter returns a `void` value. The popular "builder pattern" setter convention of returning the bean itself does not work with the standard Java Bean convention and the setter will not be found. This is a common source of problems when using the `BeanMapper`._"

Comment: Otherwise, if that does not help (I don't typically use Lombok, myself), can you provide the precise DDL for the three tables you are using?

Comment: I am not replacing the setter with builder. The builder and constructor, setter are all in the class. The issue seems to be the prefix only looks for "prefix_" not "prefix."

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the prefix looks for "prefix_" instead of "prefix."
So I will have to explicitly add the alias for the select query to work:

```
String selectSql = "SELECT t.id as t_id, t.ticket_int_1 as t_ticket_int_1, i.id as i_id ...."
```